# Input string was not in a correct format in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, drop-down-menu

Every time I run the following code, it keeps on saying "Input string was not in a correct format". I have tried it two different ways, but it is still failing. How can I fix this problem?

```
protected void CEButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["CE"] = CEDropDownList.Text;
}
```

Comment: That error message is typically seen when trying to parse a value, such as `int.Parse`, `double.Parse`, etc. Are you sure you are showing the correct code where this error is taking place?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram yes because it happens only when i click that button and that's all that there is under that button's event

Comment: To be clear, are you debugging and can actually see the exception happening at this line of code? In ASP.NET, other handlers are still in play when you have a button click. The page life-cycle executes, such as Page_Init, Page_Load, Page_PreRender.

Comment: @Seesharp, No there must be something you don't show(or see). Just put your code `Session["CE"] = CEDropDownList.Text;` to page load and see if you get an error.

Comment: yes when the button is pressed the session value becomes System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState

Comment: @L.B you right its working fine on page load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If CEDropDownList is a Dropdown contol type, you will be looking for `CEDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text`

Say your drop down list looks like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="CEDropDownList" runat="server">
      <asp:ListItem Value="foo">Bar</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

To get **foo**, you would use `CEDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text`

To get **Bar** you would use `CEDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value`

Comment: CEDropDownList is getting it's values from a SQL db

Comment: @Seesharp - Are you setting the DataTextField and DataValueField when populating from the DB?

Comment: @zeroef Quote on MSDN of the DDL's Text property: "Gets or sets the SelectedValue property of the ListControl control." I hate when people use it, but it's the exact same thing as using .SelectedValue

Comment: @Servy - I agree, but sometimes the text can differ from the value. Since the question was lacking detail, I provided a way to pull either.

Comment: Either way it's a moot point as it wouldn't cause the error the OP is seeing.  Clearly, as suggested in another person's comment, there's something else going on in Page_Load or similar that's being fired and breaking on postbacks.